# W3C Validator Errors See Below

Tags: validation, w3c

Like lots of other questioners I am having two issues with W3C Validator. Here is the code that I have in a Wordpress CMS page

```
[twocol_one]"Out of love with your kitchen. Is it time for some KGC . . .Kitchen Guidance Counselling?" Maybe we need to sit down together and see what the Duleek Olive Wood and Lime Green Fitted Kitchen does for you. With its rich Grainy Olive Wood doors mixed with the loud lime green slab doors there is definitely a statement that can be made here. Read more about Kitchen Makeovers Below!<br /><h2>Benefits Include:</h2>
<strong>
• Eye Level Oven &amp; Microwave
• Easy Access Corner Presses
• Easy to Clean
• Hydraulic Hinged Wall Units
</strong>
<h3>Shop Online - Click Below &amp; Off You GO!</h3>
[button link="http://www.kitchens4u.ie/shop" color="red"]Shop Online[/button]

[/twocol_one] [twocol_one_last]<a href="http://www.kitchens4u.ie/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Duleek-Olivewood-Lime-Green.gif"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-79" alt="the duleek olivewood and lime green fitted kitchen from kitchens4u.ie dublin ireland" src="http://www.kitchens4u.ie/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Duleek-Olivewood-Lime-Green.gif" width="300" height="225" /></a>Duleek Olive Wood and Lime Geen Fitted Kitchen - Click Image to Enlarge<br />[/twocol_one_last][hr]<br /><h3 style="text-align: center;">Kitchen Tip No. 31: When Doing DIY Kitchens</h3><br /><em>"Measure Twice - Cut Once!"</em><br />[hr]<br />[twocol_one]<h2>What We Can Do For You!</h2>[unordered_list style="bullet"]<ul><li>FREE Consultation in your home.</li>
    <li>FREE 3D Graphic Design.</li>
    <li>Plumbing Service.</li>
    <li>Electrical Service.</li>
    <li>Gas Services.</li>
    <li>Plastering Services.</li>
    <li>Ceramic Tiling.</li>
    <li>Waste Removal.</li>
    <li>Safe Disposal of Old Appliances.</li>
    <li>Full Project Management.</li>
    <li>Give you Peace of Mind.</li>
    <li>CLICK BELOW TO LET US KNOW!</li></ul>[/unordered_list]<br />[button link="http://www.kitchens4u.ie/contact-us/" size="large" color="orange"]FREE CONSTULATION[/button] [/twocol_one] [twocol_one_last]<br /><h2>Discover The Easy Stress Free Way</h2><br />A fitted kitchen is a big undertaking, but it is also investment in your home and you should do your best to make the right decisions. At Kitchens4u.ie we are always on hand to help clients understand the big picture. We will be with you every step of the way to advise you on all aspects of your fitted kitchen or bedroom project. We have all the experts when it comes to Plumbing, Electrics, Tiling, Plastering etc, so there is no need for you to worry. And to keep you stress free throughout the whole process YOU just deal with one team. <strong>The Kitchens4u Team.</strong> Discover the secret of stress FREE kitchen renovations, call us now on <strong>085-2311086</strong> or click below to arrange a FREE consultation in your home.[/twocol_one_last]
```

This is the first validation error that I cannot remove. It is in the header somewhere. I have found some scripts in PHP to remove this - I tried them but no success. If anybody can give me some help I would appreciate it. I have come across scripts that should be put in the header and also a script that should be put in the .htaccess file. Tried the script in the header - Did not Work. .htaccess file is not visible on the servier.

Here is the error: **Error Line 67, Column 64: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.**

Here is the second error. I had quite a few of these 4 to be precise and in my situation they seem to be caused by carriage returns in the CMS page. The problem with this last one is it is showing at the bottom of the page where you see home.[/twocol_one_last] - and from my point of view there is no `</div>` or `</p>` and also there is no open `<p>` at the start of the paragraph but validator is saying there is. Here is what the W3C Validator is saying on line 306

```
<p>A fitted kitchen is a big undertaking, but it is also investment in your home and you should do your best to make the right decisions. At Kitchens4u.ie we are always on hand to help clients understand the big picture. We will be with you every step of the way to advise you on all aspects of your fitted kitchen or bedroom project. We have all the experts when it comes to Plumbing, Electrics, Tiling, Plastering etc, so there is no need for you to worry. And to keep you stress free throughout the whole process YOU just deal with one team. <strong>The Kitchens4u Team.</strong> Discover the secret of stress FREE kitchen renovations, call us now on <strong>085-2311086</strong> or click below to arrange a FREE consultation in your home.</div></p>
```

And yet my `<h2>` header tag before the paragraph just runs on with a `<br />` before the paragraph starts.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "[  ]" brackets of that type on the attributes but instead use "< >" these.
please tell me if that helps and if you could provide the entire html file you are using that would be great.  for instance change the button to this:
`[button link="http://www.kitchens4u.ie/shop" color="red"]Shop Online[/button]`
tell me if that works to.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your 1. problem

I guess you didn't show us the relevant part of your code, but the error messages says that you are using a `meta` element with a `http-equiv` attribute and a value of `X-UA-Compatible`.

This is not allowed in HTML5. You may only use [values listed in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives) or [registered in the WHATWG wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions).

As you will see, `X-UA-Compatible` is a *proposed* extension. Not yet allowed, but may be in the future.

#### Your 2. problem

You are closing a `div` inside of the `p` element, but the `div` is not opened there:

```
<p>…</div></p>
```

So remove the `</div>` resp. open it inside of the `p`, whatever you need.

If you are not seeing those, you are probably using a WYSIWYG editor to edit your content. Switch to a "HTML edit" mode to see the real/produced markup.